# Is it safe to reconnect burnt wire in tower fan?

Tags: safety, wire, diy

I have a tower fan which was starting and stoping at intervals.  Taking it apart, I found that a wire connecting the mains plug to the appliance has burnt in half.  You can see the blue wire at the bottom of the image is severed.

The two ends were still touching, so that explains the inconsistent connection.

**Is it safe for me to reconnect this wire?**  I would insert a small new piece of wire and solder.

My concern is that I don't know why this part burnt in the first place.  Does it imply a more dangerous problem with the motor, or is it normal for wires to be expendable?

If it matters, this is in the UK (230 volts mains)

[image: Burnt wire]

[image: Close up]

Comment: Hi! Welcome back!

Comment: What's burnt? I can't see anything in the image.

Comment: @winny Apologies.    I have edited the photo to include a yellow arrow.  Can you see the blue wire is severed and has left some ash on the white casing?

Comment: Oh! Thanks. That's a mighty strange place for a cable to be burnt off. Is there any bending back and forth going on in that spot? I would just brush away any black residue and replace the cord as you suggest and be done with it.

Comment: @winny The bottom black plastic disk does pivot, to allow the fan to blow in alternating directions.  The wire might have some minimal bending during that process, but it would be small if any.

Comment: Wow! Bad design. Please add slack with the new cable to minimize this pinching.

Comment: Examine the black and brown wires in the vicinity—the insulation appears to be deformed. It’s possible the entire group of wires was pinched by something during manufacture or operation, and the blue wire took the brunt of it. I see a couple of metal plates in there.

Comment: With heat, insulations go through irreversable changes.  So is it safe, no.  Black looks melted.  The problem is as you point out, is why it burnt out.  I'd disassemble more to look for a cause.  I'd rewire that full assembly before using.